# Scrollable region of UIScrollview bigger than scrollview itself

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want the following. I have a navigation bar at the bottom of my app. Above I have a scrollview where the user can scroll to. Look at the image below.

[image]

Inside my scrollview I've added an image. This is what I do in code.

```
[scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(1024, 1400))];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[imgWebsite setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgWebsite.frame.size.width, 1400)];
```

**Problem**

My scrollview comes over my navigation bar at the bottom and so it is not visible. 
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `frame` of your `scrollView` as well as the `contentSize`?

Try something like this:

```
[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height - navBar.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should minus navigation's bar height from your scrollview's height and that is 44(Default). I think it works.